# Reading from a file in k6

Tags: javascript, performance, load-testing, stress-testing, k6

Is there a best practice way to read csv files for test data?

Say I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
username,password
joe,secret1
jane,secret2
bill,secret3
```

...and I want to use those usernames and passwords inside a k6 script.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! You'd use the `open()` function in the init context (outside `export default function() {...}`). Here's an example if you'd have JSON data in a file:

```
import { sleep } from "k6";

const data = JSON.parse(open("./data.json"));

export default function() {
  let user = data[__VU - 1];
  console.log(`${user.username}, ${user.password}`);
  sleep(3);
}
```

...if you have a data file `data.json` looking something like this:

```
[
  {
   "username" : "user1", 
   "password" : "test" 
  },
  {
   "username" : "user2", 
   "password" : "test" 
  }
]
```

To do the same thing with CSV, I'd look for a JS CSV parsing library and [import it as a module](https://docs.k6.io/docs/modules)